# Get v-if expression/data as plain text in child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

Hy there,

I try to create a custom Vue component which is shown based on v-if directive. I also want to change the directive data (modalStatus) value from inside the component.

```
<modal v-if="modalStatus"></modal>
```

To update the data from the component i use a method similar to this.

```
closeModal () {
   this.$parent.modalStatus = false
}
```

The problem is that sometimes i don't know the name of the data model (modalStatus) , can be anything.

My question is how can i get the data/expression name as a plain text from the modal component ?

I'm planing to use something like this to update the modalStatus

```
this.$parent['anyName'] = false
```

Thanks and stay safe !

Later Edit. I know how to accomplish all of the above using props or v-model. I wonder if is possible using strictly v-if. Thanks!

Comment: You need props on your component. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches to get to a method or property in the parent component from the child.

The 'Vue Way' is to emit a message telling the parent to close.

## Send the name in as a property

Parent

```js
<child modalName='modalStatus' />
```

Child

```js
this.$parent[this.modalName]=false
```

## Send in a method

Parent

```js
<child :close='onClose' />
```

```js
// component method
onClose(){
   this.modalStatus=false
}
```

Child

```js
this.close()
```

## Emit a message

Parent

```js
<child-component @close='modalStatus=false' />
```

```js
// or call a method
<child-component @close='onClose' />
// component method
onClose(){
  this.modalStatus=false
}
```

Child

```js
this.$emit('close')
```